# Troubleshoot kubectl DNS Lookup REFUSED

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-eks, kubectl

This is happening on one engineers Macbook. Everyone else is able to run kubectl commands successfully.

```
% kubectl --v=1000 get svc
I0326 16:22:48.587540   28045 loader.go:379] Config loaded from file:  /Users/<user>/.kube/config
I0326 16:22:48.593843   28045 round_trippers.go:425] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubectl/v1.20.4 (darwin/amd64) kubernetes/e87da0b" 'https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api?timeout=32s'
I0326 16:23:19.412689   28045 round_trippers.go:445] GET https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api?timeout=32s in 30818 milliseconds
I0326 16:23:19.412767   28045 round_trippers.go:451] Response Headers:
I0326 16:23:19.414987   28045 cached_discovery.go:121] skipped caching discovery info due to Get "https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp: i/o timeout

%nslookup XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com
Server:     192.168.86.1
Address:    192.168.86.1#53

** server can't find XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.gr7.us-east-1.eks.amazonaws.com: **REFUSED**
%
```

I deleted their $HOME/.kube and rebuilt it.
I cleared and restarted the local DNS cache.
I rebooted the macbook.
Usually this stuff clears up on it's own.

Why would one person get REFUSED and everyone else gets an address?

EDIT:
This is happening now with RDS and a different engineer. We all work remote, but this happened when people travel and work from a new location.
I don't think it's a coincidence.